# Trying to debug a web site on iPad, but the device doesn't appear under Develop menu in Safari on my Mac

Tags: ipad, safari, mobile-safari, remote-debugging

According to iOS Developer Library [Debugging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html) guide it should be possible to debug a web site in Mobile Safari (on iOS 6) remotely from desktop Safari, through a usual USB connection. But after completing described steps (*I turn on Web Inspector on iPad, connect it via USB to my Mac, switch on Develop menu form the preferences*) I still do not see any device item under Develop menu in desktop Safari. Is there any other crucial requirement for this to work? Minimal Mac OS X version maybe? I have 10.6.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that support for remote debugging was added only in Safari 6, which, for some unexplainable reason is not available for Snow Leopard, only for Lion (in limited version) and up. So I bought an upgrade to Mountain Lion and it simply works now.

Answer (score 4):

Apple wants to force the developers to upgrade to the recent OSX (which is bundled with the recent Developer Tools).

But there is an working way for debugging iOS6+ Safari for developers using OSX 10.6.8 / Windows / whatever:

[WeinRE](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html)

It works just fine like the official way. Maybe Apple took this project for their debugging (just a guess).

Comment: this answer is helpful but Weinre has a limited set of features when comparing to a "regular" webkit console  : no js debugging, lots of lag etc

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences for Safari on iOS, there is an option under advanced that allows the toggling of 'Web Inspector', which turns on and off this feature (at least this is on iOS 6, I don't have older devices to check this on).

There is also a limitation that:

> Important: You can only inspect apps on devices that have been transferred to your device from Xcode. You cannot inspect apps that have been downloaded from the App Store, even if it is your app.

So I expect that developer apps are the only other ones that you can manipulate in this manner.

Comment: I've already turned on Web Inspector under Advanced, that's the problem. According to the guide there is nothing else to do and everything should just work. But it doesn't. Maybe I need a Lion or Mountain Lion or what else has come out since Snow Leopard?